# Does Blender have these simple UV mapping options?

Tags: modeling, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm new to model building and UV mapping in Blender. I used to do my modeling/kit bashing in 3ds Max. 3ds Max has a simple way to 1) clear existing UV mapping from objects; 2) apply a UV mapping format to an entire object, e.g., Cylindrical, Spherical, etc. Does Blender have similar way to do this? Thanks. Blender 2.93.5 Windows 10

[image]

Comment: if you select all in Edit mode and press U you'll have the Cylinder Projection option

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in general.  If you enter edit mode on a mesh, select all, and hit 'u' for the unwrap menu, you'll see a list of various ways to unwrap a mesh.  That includes project from view (presumably the same as Max's "Plane"), cube projection ("Box"), cylinder projection, and sphere projection.  All of these depend on the current view in the 3D viewport from which the unwrap is called.  For all of these, you should be using an orthogonal view, pointing in the object's +Y axis.  You can get this view, in default 2.93 with any startup interface options (I believe) with numpad 1.

"Cap" options presumably unwraps the cap of cylinders to separate islands projected from view; this has to be done manually in Blender, but is a simple  project from view with cap faces selected.  XYZ to UVW doesn't make sense in Blender with only 2D UV, but XY to UV is just a plane projection from the top view, assuming the XYZ under consideration is world XYZ position.

I'm not sure what face or shrink wrap options are.  Given demonstrations of how Max handles those options, I could probably tell you how to reproduce them.

Not confident that I can guess what Max is doing with dimension and tile options, but these are probably best handled with math in the material nodes (mapping and modulo on coordinates.)  Dimensions are probably just a simple scale of UV.  Modulo on coordinates in Blender is kinda not right-- doesn't handle texture filtering correctly when you do that-- but then, I don't know that Max handles that right either.

For many of these, it's also possible to do mapping in a material's image texture node, from generated coordinates to "box", "sphere", or "tube" (cylinder) map a texture without even bothering with UV.

It's also possible to have material node groups that do plane, cylinder, sphere, or box mapping on individual samples, without regard to UV.  The math for these can be intimidating, but once done it's reusable, and I'd bet somebody has shared the node groups to do this somewhere or other.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your responses. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You can select your object, and then go to *UV workspace* on the top side. Usually it will automatically turn into *edit mode*, and select all vertices.

Then you can hit the <kbd>U</kbd> button or *UV>unwrap*,and then you can see some simple uv options.

You can follow my steps,then you can have quick UV.